# Error for nomenclature: Paragraph ended before \@@@nomenclature was complete

Tags: errors, nomenclature

I am facing the same problem. I always get the the error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@@@nomenclature was complete.
```

I am using this nomenclature:

```
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{nomentbl} 
\toprule 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\nomenclature 
\newcommand{\abk}{\nomenclature} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis} 
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize} 
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill} 
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep} 
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{% 
   \ifx#1L\relax 
     \large \bfseries Lateinische Formelzeichen 
   \fi 
   \ifx#1G\relax 
     \large \bfseries Griechische Formelzeichen 
   \fi 
   \ifx#1A\relax 
     \large \bfseries Abkürzungen 
   \fi 
   \ifx#1I\relax 
     \large \bfseries Indizes 
   \fi 
   \ifx#1K\relax 
     \large \bfseries Kennzahlen 
   \fi} 

\makenomenclature
```

Any ideas? I am using ISO-8859-15.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code you show is certainly useful, but also a minimal example of a document that produces the error is needed.

Comment: You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I had the same problem and the only mistake was that I had added a new abbreviation and forgotten to close a bracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are surely trying to define your nomenclature entries in this way:

```
\nomenclature[<prefix>]{<symbol>}{<description>}
```

which is the way to define nomenclature entries when using the `nomencl` package.

But you're using the `nomentbl` package, and the correct way to define nomenclature entries is:

```
\nomenclature[<prefix>]{<symbol>}{<description>}{<units>}{<dimension>}
```

Practically, you are missing the two last mandatory arguments.

For example, the `nomencl` entry

```
\nomenclature[L]{$F$}{Force}
```

has to be rewritten as

```
\nomenclature[L]{$F$}{Force}{N}{ML/T$^2$}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newcommand{\abk}{\nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
   \ifx#1L\relax
     \large \bfseries Lateinische Formelzeichen
   \fi
   \ifx#1G\relax
     \large \bfseries Griechische Formelzeichen
   \fi
   \ifx#1A\relax
     \large \bfseries Abkürzungen
   \fi
   \ifx#1I\relax
     \large \bfseries Indizes
   \fi
   \ifx#1K\relax
     \large \bfseries Kennzahlen
   \fi} 

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\[F=m\alpha\]

\nomenclature[L]{$F$}{Force}{N}{ML/T$^2$}
\nomenclature[L]{$m$}{mass}{kg}{M}
\nomenclature[G]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}{m/s$^2$}{L/T$^2$}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

To reproduce the error it suffices to replace the lines

```
\nomenclature[L]{$F$}{Force}{N}{ML/T$^2$}
\nomenclature[L]{$m$}{mass}{kg}{M}
\nomenclature[G]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}{m/s$^2$}{L/T$^2$}
```

with

```
\nomenclature[L]{$F$}{Force}
\nomenclature[L]{$m$}{mass}
\nomenclature[G]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}
```

Also remember that the correct command line to compile the nomenclature is:

```
makeindex.exe -s nomentbl.ist -t yourfile.nlg -o yourfile.nls yourfile.nlo
```